# Get all children recursively in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, recursion, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core we can have recursive entities. But we cannot do an "Include" for these recursives (can we?). So I wrote a `Get`-method that does it for me:

First, this is my `RecursiveEntity<T>` base-class:

```
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RecursiveEntity<TEntity> : Entity, IRecursiveEntity<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : RecursiveEntity<TEntity>
{
    public virtual TEntity Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `Repository`-base-class for recurisve entities:

```
public abstract class RecursiveRepository<T, TDataContext> 
    where T : RecursiveEntity<T> where TDataContext : DbContext
{
    protected IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        IQueryable<T> parents = DataContext.Set<T>()
            .Include(x => x.Children)
            .Where(w => w.Parent == null)
            .Where(expression);

        foreach (T entity in parents)
        {
            if (entity.Children != null && entity.Children.Any())
                entity.Children = _getChildren(entity, expression).ToList();

            yield return entity;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> _getChildren(T parentEntity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        IQueryable<T> children = DataContext.Set<T>()
            .Include(x => x.Parent)
            .Where(w => w.Parent != null && w.Parent.Id == parentEntity.Id)
            .Where(expression);

        foreach (T entity in children)
        {
            entity.Children = _getChildren(entity, expression).ToList();
            yield return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion what I can do better? 
Is it a good solution to do that many `DataContext<Set>`-accesses and assign them  to the parent with `ToList()`?

Comment: Can there be cycles in this recursive entity? For instance, can my parent be my grandchild?

Comment: @dfhwze good point! regarding database, yes, it's possible. I should handle that in my backend - no, I dont want circular references.

Comment: I don't know whether EF supports dynamic hierarchical loading. it didn't in the past. However, one way to try and solve this it is to load the objects as a flattened list and then build the hierarchy in memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you remove `virtual` from `Children` it'll work with `Include(e => e.Children)`:

```
  public abstract class RecursiveEntity<TEntity>
    : Entity, IRecursiveEntity<TEntity>
    where TEntity : RecursiveEntity<TEntity>
  {
    public virtual TEntity Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TEntity> Children { get; set; }
  }
```

The meaning with `virtual` is to provide lazy loading. If you can't live with that, you'll have to do it manually, as you do.

---

Alternatively I think, you can add "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to your connection string.

---

**UPDATE**

I seems that EF 6 and EFCore work differently when it comes to `Include`?

EFCore has the `Include()` and `ThenInclude` pattern but that is rather useless for recursive initialization.

When loading manually have you then experimented with the abilities to load navigation properties on each object as in:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) where TEntity: RecursiveEntity<TEntity>
{
  foreach (TEntity entity in Set<TEntity>().Where(e => e.Parent == null).Where(filter))
  {
    GetChildren(entity, filter);
    yield return entity;
  }
}

private void GetChildren<TEnity>(TEnity parent, Expression<Func<TEnity, bool>> childFilter) where TEnity : RecursiveEntity<TEnity>
{
  Entry(parent).Collection(e => e.Children).Query().Where(childFilter).Load();
  // Entry(parent).Reference(e => e.Parent).Load(); // I think this shouldn't be necessary because loading the children will load the parent on them

  if (parent.Children != null)
  {
    foreach (TEnity child in parent.Children)
    {
      GetChildren(child, childFilter);
    }
  }
}
```

It should produce the same result as yours, but is maybe a little clearer and in line with the EF concept.

Comment: would be nice - I tried, but in my case, it only loads the direct children. not the children of the children..

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: Strange it works in EF 6

Comment: I heared that in EF core, the "virtual" is not used anymore like in EF 6. And imho EF Core is not a "follower" of EF 6. Maybe this is not implemented. But I'll test it again later

Comment: So the reverse (child to parents) should be `Db.Entry(child).Reference(c=>c.Parent).Query().Where(filter).Load();` ????

Comment: thank you for this solution, that helped me a bunch!